# Reusing a cucumber step definition on a single page Angular app

Tags: ruby, angularjs, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I'm using watir-webdriver with the page-object gem to drive cucumber tests for a single web page app built in angular js.

The site uses a multiple stage registration process, filling a series of details each time then clicking a 'next' button. (which is enabled when all details are completed for that page)

The issue occurs when I'm attempting to reuse the following step definition:

```
And(/^I click next$/) do
 @registration = RegistrationPage.new(@browser)
 @registration.click_next
end
```

Which calls the page-object:

```
class RegistrationPage
  include PageObject

  button(:next, :value => "Next")

  def click_next
   @browser.wait_while { next_element.disabled? }
   next_element.click
  end
end
```

For the first section, the Next button is found correctly, however on the second call to the step definition, the button cannot be found, despite the button being verifiably enabled and otherwise identical.

Comment: It would help if you could give more details on how to reproduce the problem. In particular, the HTML/Javascript required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've now managed to resolve the question myself. The second iteration of the 'Next' button was running on another index, just needed to add an additional selector to catch the visible button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you've answered your question but in case it helps to explain it to anyone else:

The issue is likely that to watir it isn't the same next button on each page and all of the next buttons are in scope all of the time.  Therefore to click the correct one you would have to use the index property of the button you want i.e. index: 1 for the second page and index 2 for the the button on the third page.